# Is there any way to further optimize this MIPs code?

Tags: c, mips

```
int strlen( char* string ) {
    int count = 0;
    while( *string != ‘\0’ ) {
        string++;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I was just working on these...
I was wondering whether you can suggest any optimization?
Below is the MIPs code...

```
strlen:
li $t0, 0 # initialize the count to zero
loop:
lbu $t1, 0($a0) # load the next character into t1
beqz $t1, exit # check for the null character
addi $a0, $a0, 1 # increment the string pointer
addi $t0, $t0, 1 # increment the count
j loop # return to the top of the loop
exit:
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for code optimization, which is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
 // will (probably) output x86_64 assembly (or your computer's native assembly)
 gcc -Wall -S test.c


 // will output mips3 assembly
 gcc -Wall -march=mips3 -S test.c
```

Or with optimizations:

```
 // will output (optimized) mips3 assembly (if possible)
 gcc -Wall -O3 -march=mips3 -S test.c
```

Comment: May as well add `-O3` too.

Comment: Meh, may as well add `-pedantic`, `-std=c1x`, `-g` etc.. But that's another tale to be told.

Comment: `-2` is the number of down votes visitors have given your question. I don't know why they down voted as long as they're not writing a comment about it.

Comment: Your suggestions would make no difference to the code. My suggestion would presumably produce more "elegant" code. That was the point.

Comment: @ooga optimizations will make the code less of a "step by step" translation an more of an "anything that accomplishes the same goal (faster)" translation.

Comment: I see... I'm kinda new to SO. But anyway, thank you. And thank you for the answer, it worked.

Comment: Which means that we now are faced with a question: what is the definition of elegant in regards to assembly? Is more obscure but faster "more elegant" than less obscure and clearer but slower?

Comment: @user3314569 Don't take the down votes as discouragement, sometimes there are some rules you need to follow / acquaint yourself with, sometimes it's just people who down vote because they think the answer is "too obvious".

Comment: You just try your best to make your question clear and to the point, the rest you can learn along the way (or read in the FAQs).

Comment: I was originally asking whether anyone can reduce the above mips code. There can be a code that can produce a result. But there can be another code that can produce exactly the same result but it's shorter. I guess 'Elegant' wasn't the right word? If I confused people then my apologies... But yeah, I was also about to ask about 'gcc' stuff but you guys beat me to it...

Comment: @MihaiStancu That's probably because a request to optimize code is off-topic for SO and belongs at Code Review. Personally I think close votes are more appropriate than downvotes, which should relate to the quality of the question, not the topicality.

Comment: @user3314569 If you wanted "code optimization" then what @ooga was saying is correct the `-O` flags do that in `gcc`. I answered your question an took "elegant" to mean "readable". Update your question to mention optimizations and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @user3314569 as a side note: Wording and lingo are very important in our field. If used correctly they can help you better understand your own issue, research it better, ask better questions, get better answers etc..

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can optimize the C, though it might be tricky to figure out in the optimizer that you're allowed to do it. Compare your code to:

```
int strlen( char* string ) {
    char *sp = string;
    while( *sp != ‘\0’ ) sp++;
    return sp - string;
}
```

That should mean that the main loop contains only one addi statement instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know MIPS, but you can drop out few commands:

```
strlen:
li $t0, $a0     # init ptr
loop:
lbu $t1, 0($t0) # load the next character into t1
beqz $t1, exit # check for the null character
addi $t0, $t0, 1 # increment the string pointer
j loop # return to the top of the loop
exit:
sub $v0, $t0, $a0
```